# Can someone help me find this article on the philosophy of religion?

Tags: reference-request, theology, philosophy-of-religion

There was this essay on the current state of the field of the philosophy of religion, which made a list of uncritically accepted premises in the field, mostly because the field is subsumed with the battle between atheists and Christian apologists. I can't remember the exact number of the premises, but my best guess is eleven.

They were things like the personhood of the divine being, alternative concepts of gods such as patheism and polytheism, whether the divine creator had to create universe and none other than material universe, non-Christian, non-theistic religions are marginalized etc.

I directly downloaded the article from the author's homepage, and I can't remember the name of the author or the source of that article, other than that it was in English.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but was it this article?

https://monoskop.org/images/b/bf/Davies_Brian_An_Introduction_to_the_Philosophy_of_Religion_2nd_edition_1993.pdf